# Предложение с парными союзами

Tags: запятые, и

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставить ли запятую на месте скобок?

***Тёплая погода, если она и вернётся, то не надолго (,) и непременно будет сопровождаться сильными дождями.***

Answer (score 1):

Я могу предположить, что корректный вариант этого предложения выглядит так:

*Тёплая погода **если и** вернётся, **то** не надолго и непременно будет сопровождаться сильными дождями.*

Здесь использован **градационный двойной союз ЕСЛИ И...ТО.**

Запятая перед И не ставится, так как союз соединяет однородные сказуемые.

Сравнить: *Тёплая погода вернётся, но (вернется) не надолго и непременно будет сопровождаться сильными дождями.*

Другие градационные союзы: НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И, КАК...ТАК И, НЕ СТОЛЬКО...СКОЛЬКО, ЕСЛИ НЕ... ТО и др.

Градационные союзы рассмотрены в книге Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка".

Answer (score 1):

Запятую **не ставим** на основе следующего правила Розенталя:

После однородного члена предложения, следующего за второй частью парного союза и не заканчивающего собой предложения, запятая не ставится:
*В это лето дожди шли если не каждый день, **то через день или два** и отличались каким-то назойливым постоянством.

Работа хотя и несложная, **но трудоёмкая** и потребует дополнительного времени для своего выполнения.*